# Error in fitting a model with gee(): NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)

Tags: r, statistics

I'm fitting a gee model on a dataset including 13,500 observations (here students). Students are grouped into 52 different schools. I know that there is evidence that students are nested within schools (low ICC) and therefore I should adjust this nesting effect in the variance covariance matrix. What I'm planning to do  is to first fit a gee model with exchangeable var-cov structure. Then, on top of that, I'll run Huber-White Sandwich estimator also known as robust variance estimator. I wrote my own code for robust variance estimator and it works perfectly. My gee statement doesn't work and give the error below:

```
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)
```

Here is my code:

```
STMath.OneYr.C1 = gee(postCSTMath1Yr ~ TRT1Yr + preCSTMath + preCSTENG + 
post1YrGradeRef + ELLBaseLine + GENDER + ECODIS + ETHNICITY.F + 
as.factor(FailedInd1Yr), data = UCI.clone[UCI.clone$COHORT0809 == "C1",], 
id =  post1YrSchIID, corstr = "exchangeable")
```

Unfortunately, the code above is not reproducible for you guys and perhaps difficult to figure out what the issue is.

I appreciate if you could help me figure out to solve the issue.

Comment: Have you experimented with the family term?  Such as setting the family to "Gaussian"?

Comment: I didn't add the family parameter, but I think by default gee considers family = gaussian.

Comment: I just added the family = gaussian and I again, got the same error.

Comment: Time to break out the debugger :-(

Comment: I'm getting this same issue.  No `NA`s in the input data either.  41x4 model matrix.

Answer (score 10):

OK, this question is quite old but I ended up here, so this might help someone eventually.

Basically, this error was caused because unlike in other libraries, the `id` parameter is treated as a numeric vector.

Indeed, the `gee` function is casting `id` as a double, which I don't really understand. Here are the implicated lines (l. 119-120 of the function):

```
if (!(is.double(id))) 
  id <- as.double(id)
```

If your `id` column is a character, just cast it to a factor, or use some function (like `dplyr::min_rank`) to turn it to a numeric variable.

This should do the trick.