# Error running GEE logistic Model: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic regression model implemented through generalized estimating equations (GEEs) and keep running into the following error despite trying multiple solutions posted here on SO and elsewhere. I am unsure from where this error arises. I am using the `gee` package but the error also occurs in `geepack`.

Does anyone know why this error may be occurring despite no `NA`, `inf`, or character variables in the dataset? My suspicion is that there is something very simple I am missing, but after two days, I have to throw it to better coders than me.

Minimal data and code to reproduce the error, attempts at solutions, and relevant SO questions are below.

---

Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(7L, 1L, 20L, 15L, 14L, 6L, 8L,  24L, 21L, 19L, 5L, 4L, 18L, 
                                13L, 23L, 16L, 25L, 12L, 10L, 9L,  22L, 17L, 11L, 3L, 2L, 2L), 
                              levels = c("ALWA28M", "BOMA13M", "BOMA41M",  "DAYA35M", "DEMB72M", "EDAB3WM", "EFCH52M", 
                                         "FASI6M", "FRRO35M",  "GRAS35F", "GRKA48M", "JARA35M", "KABA27M", "KECH4WM", 
                                         "MAAD60M",  "MACH33M", "MEBA29F", "MIGU42M", "MTSA10M", "NTMA22F", "RACA2M",  
                                         "STMA35M", "TOKE39M", "TRMA12M", "YOLU29M"), class = "factor"),      
               testres = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                       levels = c("POS", "NEG"), class = "factor"), 
               agegrp = structure(c(5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
                                    3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L), 
                                  levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), 
          row.names = c(NA,  26L), 
          class = "data.frame")
```

Model

```
gee::gee(testres ~ agegrp, data = df, 
         id = id, 
         family = binomial, 
         corstr = "exchangeable")
```

Error

> Error in gee::gee(testres ~ agegrp, data = df, id = id, family = binomial,  :
> NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)
> In addition: Warning message:
> In gee::gee(testres ~ agegrp, data = df, id = id, family = binomial,  :
> NAs introduced by coercion

Checking data to ensure no `NA`, `Inf`, or character variables - all are factors with no missing data

```
# All factors
str(df)

  # 'data.frame':   26 obs. of  3 variables:
  # $ id     : Factor w/ 25 levels "ALWA28M","BOMA13M",..: 7 1 20 15 14 6 8 24 21 19 ...
  # $ testres: Factor w/ 2 levels "POS","NEG": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  # $ agegrp : Factor w/ 6 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 5 3 3 5 1 1 2 2 1 2 ...

# No NAs or Infinites
lapply(df, table, useNA = "always")
  # 0 NAs
lapply(df, \(x) table(is.infinite(x)))
 # All FALSE
```

Alternative approach using `geepack`

```
geepack::geeglm(testres ~ agegrp,
                data = df, id = id,
                corstr = "exchangeable",
                family = "binomial")
```

`geepack` error:

> Error in lm.fit(zsca, qlf(pr2), offset = soffset) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
> using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
> 2: In Ops.factor(y, mu) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Changing the correlation structure yields same error. Standard logistic regression converges:

```
summary(glm(testres ~ agegrp, data = df, family = "binomial"(link = logit)))
```

SO questions that did not resolve the issue. While this issue is common on the site, in my view there is not a sufficient answer to this question on SO, hence the decision to post.

1. [How to eliminate "NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 7)" running predict with randomForest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964078/how-to-eliminate-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-7-running-predict-w)
2. [R: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390978/r-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-1)
3. [Error in fitting a model with gee(): NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461382/error-in-fitting-a-model-with-gee-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-3)
4. [NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73119365/na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-2)
5. [NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956616/na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-5)
6. [lme: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900270/lme-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-3)
7. [NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1) when trying to run a PGLS (Pagel's lambda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104342/na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-1-when-trying-to-run-a-pgls-pagels-l)
8. [How to eliminate “NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)” in bigglm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837276/how-to-eliminate-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-3-in-bigglm)
9. [R error in glmnet: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858124/r-error-in-glmnet-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call)

Comment: @Quinten Thank you - `testres` is a factor and my data are in a data.frame - when I run `?gee::gee` it indicates that the `data = ` argument accepts a data frame, and all the solutions suggest that `testres` should be a factor. I have also run other GEE models using the `gee` package as a data frame/factors without issue. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I think values of the binary dependent variable (`testres`) need to be `1` and `0` or `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Try changing them to see if it works. I haven't tried with `gee::gee` (because I didn't install it), but it worked when I tried with `geepack::geeglm`.

Comment: @LC-datascientist perfect - that seemed to be the problem and it works with `gee`. Interesting that all the other solutions suggested turning the character rvariable (`POS`, `NEG`) into a factor. Quickly - is there a reason/preference of `geepack` over `gee`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 0 and 1 in `testres` works:

```r
  df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(7L, 1L, 20L, 15L, 14L, 6L, 8L,  24L, 21L, 19L, 5L, 4L, 18L,
                                13L, 23L, 16L, 25L, 12L, 10L, 9L,  22L, 17L, 11L, 3L, 2L, 2L),
                              levels = c("ALWA28M", "BOMA13M", "BOMA41M",  "DAYA35M", "DEMB72M", "EDAB3WM", "EFCH52M",
                                         "FASI6M", "FRRO35M",  "GRAS35F", "GRKA48M", "JARA35M", "KABA27M", "KECH4WM",
                                         "MAAD60M",  "MACH33M", "MEBA29F", "MIGU42M", "MTSA10M", "NTMA22F", "RACA2M",
                                         "STMA35M", "TOKE39M", "TRMA12M", "YOLU29M"), class = "factor"),
               testres = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)),
               agegrp = structure(c(5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L,
                                    3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L),
                                  levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")),
          row.names = c(NA,  26L),
          class = "data.frame")

gee::gee(testres ~ agegrp, data = df,
         id = id,
         family = binomial,
         corstr = "exchangeable")
#> Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
#> running glm to get initial regression estimate
#>   (Intercept)       agegrp1       agegrp2       agegrp3       agegrp4 
#>  1.956607e+01 -3.377525e-08 -1.817977e+01 -1.831331e+01 -1.887292e+01 
#>       agegrp5 
#> -3.513736e-08
#> Error in gee::gee(testres ~ agegrp, data = df, id = id, family = binomial, : Cgee: error: logistic model for probability has fitted value very close to 1.
#> estimates diverging; iteration terminated.
```

There is now an error because the model has fitted some probabilities very close to 0 or 1, but I think this is an unrelated problem (see the section Details in `?glm`).